# Getting specific passed parameter from $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `gridview` which I want it's rows to expand and display the passed BatchID.
At the moment I'm using `href="javascript:switchViews('div<%# Eval("BatchID")%>', 'one');"` to pass the information but I can't get the BatchID on the Javascript end.

At the javascript end I should get this information to assign my new rows with an ID so when I toggle them, they don't all get removed, but only the corresponding ones. At the moment, all created `tr`'s get to be removed from every `row` if toggled and also the text "`Hide Details`" remains on other rows which are not clicked but their nested tr's get removed.

I have tried to get the BatchID from the params but I don't know how. Any ideas for the above two problems?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (params) {

        $('.showDetails').click(function () {
            // Show Details DIV
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.details').toggle('fast');
            // Return false to disable default postback on click of a <a> element
            return false;
        }).toggle(
            function () {
                // Trigger text/html to toggle to when hiding.
                $(this).html('Hide Details').stop();
                $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr class='" + event.id + "'><td></td><td colspan = '999'><div>" + '111' + "</div></td></tr>");
                // $(this).closest('tr').find('.details').append('<div class=' + 'shit' + '>3399</div>');

            },
            function () {
                // Trigger text/html to toggle to when showing.
                $(this).html('Show Details').stop();
                //$(this).find('.zoom').remove();
                $('tr.' + event.id).remove();
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Gridview:

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

               <a class="showDetails" href="javascript:switchViews('div<%# Eval("BatchID")%>', 'one');">Show Details</a>

            </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I highly recommend you don't mix jQuery and inline javascript.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I am not sure how to proceed. I don't have much experience on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

> I can't get the BatchID on the Javascript end.

Lets add that to the HTML in a non-coupled way:

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

```
<a class="showDetails" data-batchid="<%# Eval("BatchID")%>" href="javascript:void(0)">Show Details</a>
```

Then update your click to get the value and make the call:

(https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

```
$('.showDetails').click(function () {

  // Show Details DIV
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.details').toggle('fast');

  var batchId = $(this).data('batchid');
  switchViews(batchId, 'one');
})....
```

I added a valid Href and remove the `return false`:

[Href attribute for JavaScript links: “#” or “javascript:void(0)”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)